# Button on QToolbar not visually responding

Tags: qt

I have a strange issue when creating a QToolbar. The buttons are simply not visibly responding to clicks, although the slot is getting called. I have tried to create the buttons in two ways as shown below. Not sure exactly what the problem is.

```
#include "toolbar.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

MyToolbar::MyToolbar(QWidget *parent):
    QToolBar(parent)
{

    back_action = new QAction(this);
    QIcon *back_icon = new QIcon(":/images/back.png");
    back_action->setIcon(*back_icon);
    addAction(back_action);
    connect (back_action, SIGNAL (clicked()), this, SLOT(do_stuff()));


    QIcon *forward_icon = new QIcon(":/images/forward.png");
    QToolButton *forwardButton = new QToolButton (this);
    forwardButton ->setIcon(*forward_icon);
    forwardButton ->setToolTip ("Forward");
    forwardButton -> setEnabled(true);
    addWidget(forwardButton);
    connect (forwardButton, SIGNAL (clicked()), this, SLOT(do_stuff()));

}

void MyToolbar::do_stuff(void) {
    cout << "Doing stuff" << endl;
}
```

The header file is here:

```
#ifndef TOOLBAR_H
#define TOOLBAR_H
#include <QToolBar>

class MyToolbar : public QToolBar {

  Q_OBJECT

  public:
    MyToolbar(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    QAction *back_action;
    QAction *forward_action;
    QAction *settings_action;

  private slots:
    void do_stuff();
    void gotoOverviewPage();


};

#endif // TOOLBAR_H
```

Comment: `Q_OBJECT`  is needed, did you add it?

Comment: I made some small changes and can confirm the slots are working. The problem is there is no visual feedback on the button.

Comment: Ah, you edited post and changed to different topic. I am sorry, what do you mean by visual feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see here is absence of `Q_OBJECT`.
`QObject` based class with signals and slots needs to have `moc` run on them to generate additional code for accepting signals and slots.

Another one is `public slot/private`. If you don't add `slots` then they won't be regarded as slots.

Also, The way you are using to connect is not the latest version although, it won't cause problem for now.

```
connect(
    sender, &Sender::valueChanged,
    receiver, &Receiver::updateValue
);
```

[New Signal And slot Syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax)